# How to center a rectangle using mark_rectangle in Altair

Tags: python, altair

Thank you for all the feedback, hopefully after this edits is a bit more clear:

The version of Altair I am using is 4

The objective is to generate a chart that when I give a keyword input, it will highlight the images that matches that keyword (I am still working on developing this code) at this moment  I just want a chart with the rect mark centered behind the image mark, just like the image below.

[Example Imagee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M09mE.png)

For the mark_image I will encode the img urls  using the 'x' and 'y' variables.

For the mark_rect I will encode the 'x' and 'y' values  used for the mark images above, I want the rectangle marks centered around the 'x' ,'y' values.

This is the toy code I am generating based on the feedback received

This is what I  have tried without success:

```py
    import altair as alt
    import pandas as pd

    data = pd.DataFrame({
            'x': [10, 20, 30, 40],
            'y': [5, 15, 25, 35]
                       })

    # This will be replaced by mark_image, this is for the toy example.
    base = alt.Chart(data).mark_point(width=500,height=500,
                                      color = 'red'
                                     ).encode(alt.X('x'), alt.Y('y'))

    # This is where I need help.
    rect = base.mark_rect().encode(
                      x=alt.X('x:Q', axis=None),
                      y=alt.Y('y:Q', axis=None),
                      x2=alt.X2('x:Q', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
                      y2=alt.Y2('y:Q', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False))                       
                      )

   base + rect
```

The error I am getting is:

```py
SchemaValidationError: Invalid specification

        altair.vegalite.v4.schema.channels.X2, validating 'additionalProperties'

        Additional properties are not allowed ('scale', 'offset' were unexpected)
```

****UPDATE

The following code solves this question :

```py
    rect = base.mark_rect(height = 50, width = 60).encode(alt.X('x'), 
    alt.Y('y'))
```

Comment: Please include a [mre] with sample data so that others can copy and run your code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why did you expect `scale` to work here?  Did you read that somewhere?

Comment: Yes, correct , somewhere I read  and I interpreted incorrectly that that would make the center of the rectangle to be located on the encoded variables.

Comment: I found out that I can use height and weight properties in the mark_rect() and that solves my question , I am not sure  how to close this question but now it is solved ,

Comment: @chris_diaz The best way to "close" this question is to post your solution as an answer and click the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as "solved"